# How to display objects into table using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have the data of objects like this:

```
 var details = {  
            3:{
               2015-3-17 : 1,
               2015-3-18 : 0,
               routelines: "PASAY - CAGAYAN",
               tripcode: 3
              },
            4:{ 
               2015-3-17 : 0
               2015-3-18 : 4
               routelines: "PASAY - CAVITE",
               tripcode:4        
              },
 }
```

Now I am planning to display them in table but I am not sure how to start since they are all objects. I want to achieve the output which looks like this:

`tripcode |    routlines   | 2015-3-17 | 2015-3-18|
     3    |PASAY - CAGAYAN |      1    |     0    |
     4    |PASAY - CAVITE  |       0   |     4    |`

Is there someone know how to do it? 
I tried this but unfortunately it's not work.

```
<div ng-repeat="detail in details">
  <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in detail">
      {{key}} : {{value}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to say that the structure of your objects is dynamic? And number and names of fields may differ?

Comment: Yes they are dynamic. .I declared it here as static as a summary because the entire data is get from database.

Comment: Duplicate of [modelling data from rows to columns in Angular dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25482857/modelling-data-from-rows-to-columns-in-angular-dynamically)

Comment: I think this is a nice question +1 . i am waiting for some other answer :) .. I think your array structure is bad.

Comment: @RameshRajendran Hi, what do you mean by bad? it is mean I should change it?

Comment: this array format have some typo errors in your date object.

Comment: i will give the answer . wait few mins

Comment: Why are you waiting to answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to format your data object correctly, some keys were missing quotes. Also details should be bound to $scope.

Try this:

```js
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    
    $scope.details = {
        '3': {
            tripcode: 3,
            routelines: "PASAY - CAGAYAN",
            '2015 - 3 - 17': 1,
            '2015 - 3 - 18': 0
        },
        '4': {
           tripcode: 4,
           routelines: "PASAY - CAVITE",
           '2015 - 3 - 17': 0,
           '2015 - 3 - 18': 4
        },
    };
    
}
```

```css
.header,
.items {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
 width: 600px;
}

.header span,
.items span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 120px;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="detail in details">
            <div class="header" ng-show="$index == 0">
                <span ng-repeat="(key, value) in detail">{{key}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="items">
                <span ng-repeat="(key, value) in detail">{{value}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have missed `$scope`

please change `var details` to `$scope.details`